# Python increment in a list

Tags: python, list, api, increment

i have this code below :

```
list = [254,255,256]

# Getting length of list using len() function
length = len(list)
i = 0
counter = 0

while i < length:
  
  url = "https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(list[i], counter) 
  i += 1
  counter += 1
  print(url)
```

Output :

```
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
```

But i want this output, with the last number (counter) 0 to 3 to every item on the list :

```
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=0&limit=50 
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
 https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
```

How can i get this result ?

Answer (score 1):

Compute a *product* of two individual lists, `[254, 255]` and `[0,1,2,3]`. Then you can simply iterate over the pairs in the product with one loop.

```
from itertools import product


template = "https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50"

for project, start in product([254,255], [0,1,2,3]):
    url = template.format(project, counter)
```

Comment: Another answer with a differente way to do it. Thanks for the helppppp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping two counters, you can use `for` loops like this:

```
urlformat = "https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50"

items = [254,255,256]

for item in items:
    for j in range(4):
        url = urlformat.format(item, j) 
        print(url)
```

Result:

```
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
```

Comment: Ty for the help bro, aprecciate

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [254,255,256]

# Getting length of list using len() function
length = len(lists)


for li in range(length):
    for count in range(4):
        url = "https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(lists[li], count)
        print(url)
```

result:

```
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
```

and never use built-in as variable please

Comment: Aprecciate bro, thanks for the help. That was a very simples solution, i was struggling for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    for item in list:
        for i in range(4):
            url = f"https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{item}/tarefa?start= 
            {i}&limit=50"
            print(url)
```

using f string is much better than using .format() str method in most cases i recommend you read about it in python documentation.
Alas the above code will give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be, as @chepner suggested, computing the cartesian product of two lists; namely `[254, 255, 256]` and `[0,1,2,3]` to obtain:

```swift
[(254, 0), (254, 1), (254, 2), (254, 3), (255, 0), (255, 1), (255, 2), (255, 3), (256, 0), (256, 1), (256, 2), (256, 3)]
```

Then, `map` the anonymous function:

```swift
lambda xy: template.format(xy[0], xy[1]),
```

over that list of pairs to produce the desired output, and join the list using the newline character `("\n")`.

```py
def main():
    template = "https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50"
    xs = [254, 255, 256]
    ys = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    cartesianProduct = [(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]
    print(
        "\n".join(map(
            lambda xy: template.format(xy[0], xy[1]),
            cartesianProduct
        ))
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/254/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/255/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=0&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=1&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=2&limit=50
https://test/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/256/tarefa?start=3&limit=50
```